# Electron density Saha Ionization Equation

Tags: astrophysics, laser, plasma-physics, ionization-energy

Saha-Boltzmann equation describes the ratio of number densities between any two consecutive ionization states and its product with the number electron density i.e.

$$n_e\frac{n_{i+1}}{n_{i}}$$

Here, $n_e$ is the electron number density, $n_{i+1}$ is the number density in $i+1$ ionization state and $n_i$ is the number density in the $i$ ionization state. My question is regarding the factor $n_e$. Which electron density is this actually? Is it the electron density produced as a result of ionization from $i$ state to $i+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which electron density is this actually?

The electron density in the [Saha equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation) is the total electron number density.  It does not really matter from where the electrons arose for the equation purposes, it's just the total electron density.

> Is it the electron density produced as a result of ionization from $i$ state to $i + 1$?

Perhaps or perhaps not.  Again, this is not the issue so much as $n_{e}$ corresponds to the total electron number density.

Comment: From any ionization state? Means it is just the free electrons in the plasma?

Comment: In my application the electrons are only created from ionization.

Comment: As I said, it does not matter from where they came.  Yes, $n_{e}$ is the number density of the free electrons in the plasma.